# Installing GCC 9.2.0 using MSYS2 on Windows

Tags: gcc, compilation, mingw-w64, msys2, gcc9

After installing MSYS2 and updating all packages and installing gcc toolchain using `pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

[image]

I have the 9.2.0 version as shown in the picture above. But when i run `gcc.exe --version` it says 8.1.0

[image]

What is causing this and how can I update to 9.2.0? The reason why I'm doing this is https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/.

Comment: The command is `gcc`, not `gcc.exe`.  You might have some other installation of gcc.exe in your path. Typing `which gcc.exe` should show you where that one was found .

Comment: @M.M Thanks, it turns out it was using MinGW-64 installed separately. Deleting it helped.

Comment: OK, glad you have solved it

Comment: Based on experience I would recommend not adding any compiler to your permanent path, instead invoke a batch file or shell script when opening a command prompt to add the compiler just for that window . (like MSYS2 does)